# Как сделать скрипт удаления пробелов из тектса

Tags: javascript

я пытался сделать так:

```js
function DeleteSpaces() {
  var code = $('#source').val();
 var compressCode = [];
 var word = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
  if (code[i] != " ") {
   compressCode[word]+=code[i];
  } else {
   word++;
  }
 }
}
```

Но в итоге первый елемент - undefined, только после идет текст и с пробелами все нормально

Comment: вообще-вообще все пробелы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var compressCode = code.replace(/ /g, "");
var reducedBy = code.length - compressCode.length;
```

Comment: нужно сделать массив из слов

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy, `code.split(/\s+/)`?

Comment: Да, все роботает, code.split(/\s+/) помог